# How exactly 'abs()' and 'argsort()' works together

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
#Creating DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7], 'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]}); df
```

output:

```
    AAA  BBB  CCC
0    4   10  100
1    5   20   50
2    6   30  -30
3    7   40  -50
```

aValue = 43.0

```
df.loc[(df.CCC-aValue).abs().argsort()]
```

output:

```
   AAA  BBB  CCC
1    5   20   50
0    4   10  100
2    6   30  -30
3    7   40  -50
```

> The output confusing, can you please explain in detail how the below line
>   works

```
df.loc[(df.CCC-aValue).abs().argsort()]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `abs` flipping negative values, and the subtraction shift values around, it's hard to visualize what's going on.  Instead I need to calculate it step by step:

```
In [97]: x = np.array([100,50,-30,-50])
In [98]: x-43
Out[98]: array([ 57,   7, -73, -93])
In [99]: abs(x-43)
Out[99]: array([57,  7, 73, 93])
In [100]: np.argsort(abs(x-43))
Out[100]: array([1, 0, 2, 3])
In [101]: x[np.argsort(abs(x-43))]
Out[101]: array([ 50, 100, -30, -50])
```

`argsort` is the indexing that puts the elements in sorted order.  We can see that with:

```
In [104]: Out[99][Out[100]]
Out[104]: array([ 7, 57, 73, 93])
```

or

```
In [105]: np.array([57, 7, 73, 93])[[1, 0, 2, 3]]
Out[105]: array([ 7, 57, 73, 93])
```

`How they work together` is determined by the Python syntax; that's straight forward.

Comment: It means the only index is sorted where values are unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

`(df.CCC-aValue).abs()` will take the absolute value of the `df.CCC-aValue`, and `argsort` will sort the values and takes the sorted indexes, and `df.loc` will show the rows with sorted indexes

Comment: Those values in 'CCC' column if they match with 'aValue' then it makes absolute value and then sorted ?

Comment: Its not about matching, the values in `CCC` are subtracted by an amount of `aValue`

Comment: If aValue is subtracted from 'CCC'  column values then values in 'CCC' columns aren't changed? can you explain in detail ?

Comment: @jain you could simply try these things out in an IDE